# How to write a video stream containing B-frame and no DTS to a MP4 container?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, rtsp, rtp, muxer

I want to save a h264 video stream received from a RTSP source to a MP4 container.
Not like other questions asked on SO, here the challenges I face are:

- The stream contains B frames.
- The stream has only PTS given by the RTP/RTCP.

Here is the code I did

```
//  ffmpeg
    pkt->data = ..;
    pkt->size = ..;
    pkt->flags = bKeyFrame? AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY : 0;    
    pkt->dts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
    pkt->pts = PTS;

    // PTS is based on epoch microseconds so I ignored re-scaling.
    //av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, { 1, AV_TIME_BASE }, muxTimebase);

    auto ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(m_pAVFormatCtx, pkt);
```

I received a lot of error messages like this: 
    "Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer ...".

Result: the mp4 file is playable via VLC but the FPS is just a half of the original FPS and the video duration is incorrect (VLC shows a weird number).

So how do I set correct DTS and PTS before sending to the container?

**Update:**
I have tried some changes, though not successfully yet, I found that the reason of the frame rate drop is due to the muxer discards frames having incorrect DTS.
Additionally, if I set start of PTS and DTS value too big, some players like VLC has to delay some time before showing video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done several experiments and have some things to share to you.

1. Regardless having B-frames or not, mp4 muxer requires DTS must be (at least):

   - Monotonically increasing.
   - DTS <= PTS per each frame.
   - PTS and DTS should start from values close to zero (otherwise players like VLC has to delay some time before displaying video).
2. If there is no B-frames in the stream, DTS could be copied from PTS and saving frames to
   a mp4 file without any issue.
3. If there are B-frames in the stream, the story is total different.
   In this case, PTS of frames are not monotonically increased due to B-frames.
   Hence, just copying DTS = PTS definitely won't work. We have to find a way to 
   have DTS by either sending DTS via out-of-band or calculating from FPS and PTS.

For sending out-of-band, it is quite complicated because it requires handling both
RTSP server and RTSP client. Here I just want to show the simple way of deducing DTS from FPS and PTS.

Rough steps are like this:

**Detects average duration (or FPS) between frames**

- Parses FPS from SDP of receiving RTSP session. This way depends on
  support of RTSP server. Some support, others do not.
- Another way is to calculate average duration between frames from sequence of
  frames. You can buffer number of frames equal to size of one GOP,
  getting the PTS difference of the first and the last frame of the GOP
  divided by the number of frames you will have the average duration.
  Example, if the FPS is assumed 30, then calculated average duration
  should be approx 33,333 us.

**Saving to the container**

```
// Initialize container

    pAVStream->time_base = { 1, AV_TIME_BASE }; // PTS/DTS in microseconds.
    pAVFormatCtx->oformat->flags |= AVFMT_SEEK_TO_PTS;
    ret = avformat_write_header(m_pAVFormatCtx, &priv_opts);

    Assume that you have pre-calculated average duration: 
    nAvgDuration = 33'333LL;

    //  Per each frame

    if (waitingForTheFirstKeyFrame) {
        if (!bsKeyFrame) {
            return false;
        }

        waitingForTheFirstKeyFrame = false;
        nPTSOffset = nPTS; // pts will start from 0
        nStartDTS = nPTS - nAvgDuration; // dts will start from -nAvgDuration
    }

    nDTS = nStartDTS;
    nStartDTS += nAvgDuration; // dts is monotonically increasing

    pkt->pts = nPTS - nPTSOffset;
    pkt->dts = nDTS - nPTSOffset;

    //  Since PTS/DTS are in microseconds, no need to rescalling more.
    //  Of course, you can use a different time_base.

    auto ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(m_pAVFormatCtx, pkt);
```

**Caution:**

This solution works well with an assumption that the original PTS of the stream (at server side) are monotonically increased, there are no gaps between frames and there is no frame loss. Otherwise, the accuracy of DTS may be reduced or even the mp4 file could not be played.

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal that "**The stream has only PTS given by the RTP/RTCP.**". Something wrong here.
If there is no dts, it means you should use pts only. If there are really B frames, then you would have dts values that different than pts.

Try on your code `dts = pts` and see what happens.

Comment: @kamilz Nothing wrong here. As I mentioned earlier, the stream come from a RTSP source, naturally there is no DTS you could retrieve from RTSP streaming.
What did you mean "try pts = dts" while dts does not exist?
Even you really meaned "dts = pts", it won't work because dts must be 
linearly increased.
I am trying to calculate dts basing on pts and frame-rate.

Comment: Yes, "dts = pts" I meant. Anyway are you sure about this ? "naturally there is no DTS you could retrieve from RTSP streaming."

Comment: Yes, I am. No DTS is carried in RTP/RTCP channels unless you sent it out-of-band. You can check that in the RTSP RFC(s).

Comment: I see.. so in this case you can either tell your source to send oob data for dts or, do not use b-frames. I don't see another solution. But if you find anything, please share I'm really curious if somewhat you can produce correct dts'.

Comment: Sure, I will share the solution when I have it. Thanks for your attention.